# JQuery message im magento 1, need to be adjusted for non-repetition and translation-ready

Tags: magento-1.9, php, jquery

I have two issues in this code:

```
1: if I keep clicking on the radio button the message will be repeated. 
2: I cannot translate the message to other language.
```

**Here is my jquery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#co-payment-form dt input').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'paytabs_server'){
            $(this).next().append('<span id="paytab_message">Please make sure to enable Cookies from your browser!</span>')
        }else{
            $('#paytab_message').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use .one():

 $('#co-payment-form dt input').one('click', function(){


});

To execute only once click funcation

Comment: Did you write this script on any phtml file?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I have added this script in my footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code, it should work if you are using the script in your footer.phtml file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var text = "<?php echo $this->__('Please make sure to enable Cookies from your browser!') ?>";
        $('#co-payment-form dt input').on('click', function(){
            if($(this).val() == 'paytabs_server'){
                if($('#paytab_message').length == 0)
                    $(this).next().append('<span id="paytab_message">'+text+'</span>')
            }else{
                $('#paytab_message').remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! ..thank you alot @Sukumar Gorai

Comment: Welcome. Happy to Help!